# Numpy polyfit returns an array, while I expect a single number

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

I have two lists, `x` and `y' based on which I want to fit a linear line.

To do so, I use the following code:

```
x = df[quality][df['model'].str.contains(cluster, case=False, na=False)].to_numpy()
y = df[prediction][df['model'].str.contains(cluster, case=False, na=False)].to_numpy()
slope, constant = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

I expected the slope and the constant to be one number (since I am using 1 degree in `np.polyfit`. But instead, it's a NumPy array:

```
print(slope)
>>> [ 1.07032587 -0.07121294]

print(constant)
>>> [0.13656049 0.08582967]
```

How can I interpret these numbers? And which values can I use to fit a line?

Comment: I think it would help to know a bit more about your data. Can you just share a minimal example, using arrays of numbers, instead of pandas code?

Comment: That answered my question already. I disregarded the fact that I was capturing two values in `y`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because your x and y have different dimension.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
>>> y  = np.array([[1,6],[3, 3], [5,9], [7,5]])
>>> slope, constant = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
>>> slope
array([1.  , 0.15])
>>> constant
array([2.66453526e-15, 5.15000000e+00])
```

To make sure they both have same dimension,

```
>>> assert x.ndim == y.ndim
```

Correct way should be ,

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
>>> y = np.array([ 6, 3, 9, 5 ])
>>> assert x.ndim == y.ndim
>>> slope, constant = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
>>> slope
0.14999999999999963
>>> constant
5.150000000000002
```